# Loading then saving a wav with librosa is adding distortion

Tags: python, librosa

I tried saving the wave with the Python library `soundfile` as well and has the same issue. Seems like maybe I am loading things wrong...? Not sure how that is with such a simple API.

```py
librosa.output.write_wav("../resources/output/test.wav", *librosa.load("../resources/waves/missingout.wav"))
```

When I run the above code the test.wav file plays and I can hear the audio but there is a substantial amount of noise added...

Comment: It may be helpful to look at the files in a hex editor. I see that `librosa.load` returns wave data and a sample rate, but there is additional information that may be getting lost. I suspect the ByteRate and BitsPerSample may be different http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: By default, `librosa.load()` resamples the file to 22050 Hz mono (see docs at https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html). That may be part of it.